# Как решить проблему с вызовом shortcode прямо из темплейта?

Tags: wordpress

У меня функция в functions.php, которая скрывает css & js от плагина Contact Form 7 там, где он не используеся, то есть где не вставлен шорткод, [contact-form-7 id="1111"].

Но на многих страницах CF7 вызывается прямо из темплейта

```
<?= do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1111" title="Submit"]') ?>
```

Так вот, код (который ниже) этого не понимает. Он понимает шорткод внутри поста, но не понимает шорткод внутри темплейта (выше).

functions.php

```
function cf7unloaded_deregister_contact_form() {
  global $post;
    if ( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'contact-form-7' ) ) {
        remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpcf7_do_enqueue_scripts');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cf7unloaded_deregister_contact_form', 2 );
```

Comment: можно так     if ( ! is_singular( 'custom-post' ) ) {

Answer (score 0):

**Можно пойти следующим путём:**

1. Отключить вывод скриптов и стилей плагина;
2. Повесить на хук `shortcode_atts_wpcf7` их подключение (или любой другой хук, который срабатывает при преобразовании шорткода).

**Теоретическое решение:**

```
<?php
function wpcf7_remove_assets() {
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_css', '__return_false' );
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_remove_assets' );
function wpcf7_add_assets( $atts ) {
    wpcf7_enqueue_styles();
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_wpcf7', 'wpcf7_add_assets' );
```

Более подробно смотрите в статье "[Contact Form 7 — советы, хаки, секреты](https://wp-kama.ru/id_7943/contact-form-7-sovety-haki-sekrety.html)"